# WooCommerce products custom loop filtered by an array of SKUs

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce, product

I have an array which has a couple of product SKU's in it I want to dispay the products that are connected to the SKU's.

I found the custom woocommerce product loop, but can't find any documentation on how to extend this.

```
$skus = array(sku1, sku2, sku3);

$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'product',
  'post_status'    => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );

  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `WP_Query`, you will need to use a **meta query** to get products that are connected to an array of SKUs.

The code:

```
$skus = array('sku1', 'sku2', 'sku3');

$loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array( array(
        'key'     => '_sku',
        'value'   => $skus,
        'compare' => 'IN',
    ) ),
) );

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Tested and works.

See [`WP_Query` and custom field post meta parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters) documentation

Comment: Any chance you can tell me how I can sort the products based on the array list. I want to always keep the same sorting of the sku's in the array. For example array(sku2, sku3, sku1) should always show sku2 first, sku3 second.....

Comment: @CrisC try to add to the query array: `'orderby' => 'meta_value',` … see all parameters on WP_query documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Comment: I tried this but didn't work. I've made a workaround and used wc_get_product_id_by_sku to turn the SKU's in product ID's and used ```orderby' => 'post__in',```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do this

```
$skus = array(sku1, sku2, sku3);

$meta_query = array['relation' => 'OR',];

foreach ($skus as $sku) {
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key' => '_sku',
        'value' => $sku,
        'compare' => '='
    ),
}

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => $meta_query
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );

    endwhile;
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```